# uniform convergence of $S_n=\frac{nx}{1+n^2x^3}$

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

comment about the uniform convergence of the series, whose partial sum of n terms is $S_n=\frac{nx}{1+n^2x^3}$
, for all real x.

for showing uniform convergence, I tried to use the definition $∀\epsilon>0$: $∃ m∈N$ such that $|f_n(x)−f(x)|<ϵ \ \ \forall n>m(ϵ)$.

but unable to get any expression in terms of n for which I can find the supremum and show uniform convergence, also how should I work with an interval so that I can get a feasible solution?

any hint would be highly appreciated.

ps: so its not uniform convergent for R THEN what interval should be taken such that it is uniform convergent

Comment: Uniform convergence on what?

Comment: for all real x ie on R

Comment: This is not true

Comment: I agree, it does not seem to converge uniformly for $x$ around 0. Moreover, $S_n$ is not defined for all $x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $x_n = \frac1{n^{\frac23}}$ can you see that the limit of $S_n(x_n)$ is $\infty$?

Comment: thank you......

Answer (score 0):

You can show $$ k_n=\sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}} \bigg| \frac{nx}{1+n^2x^3}\bigg|=\infty$$
This follows it is not U.C.

Comment: for what interval this will have uniform convergence

Comment: so i will find the supremum in [0,1] which i can easily get by differentiating right?

Comment: @SvidiRuns yes then show $k_n \to 0$

Comment: okay i got it, but how can i show it with traditional definition, rather than using uniform convergence test

Comment: The convergence is not uniform on [0,1]

Comment: @Kroki what am i missing?

Comment: Look to my answer if you take $x_n$ you will find that the limit is infinite. You need to go away from zero if you want a uniform convergence.

Comment: @ Oops sorry. i missed it